# Google Maps API v3 custom image tile not visible in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used Google map API to create a custom image Map. Tiles are visible in Chrome but in Firefox, tiles are not visible. All other controls of Google  map is visible and working but tiles are not visible though tiles are loading on page as I have checked with firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var centreLat = 0.0;
    var centreLon = 0.0;
    var initialZoom = 0;
    var imageWraps = false; //SET THIS TO false TO PREVENT THE IMAGE WRAPPING AROUND
    var map; //the GMap3 itself
    var gmicMapType;

    function GMICMapType() {
        this.Cache = Array();
        this.opacity = 1.0;
    }
    GMICMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
    GMICMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 19;
    GMICMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
        var c = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var c = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var tilex = coord.x,
            tiley = coord.y;
        if (imageWraps) {
            if (tilex < 0) tilex = c + tilex % c;
            if (tilex >= c) tilex = tilex % c;
            if (tiley < 0) tiley = c + tiley % c;
            if (tiley >= c) tiley = tiley % c;
        } else {
            if ((tilex < 0) || (tilex >= c) || (tiley < 0) || (tiley >= c)) {
                var blank = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
                blank.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
                blank.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
                return blank;
            }
        }
        var img = ownerDocument.createElement('IMG');
        var d = tilex;
        var e = tiley;
        var f = "t";
        for (var g = 0; g < zoom; g++) {
            c /= 2;
            if (e < c) {
                if (d < c) {
                    f += "q"
                } else {
                    f += "r";
                    d -= c
                }
            } else {
                if (d < c) {
                    f += "t";
                    e -= c
                } else {
                    f += "s";
                    d -= c;
                    e -= c
                }
            }
        }

        //var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
        //alert(fname);
        img.id = "t_" + f;
        img.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
        img.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
        img.src = "./news/27-04-2014/1/" + f + ".jpg";
        this.Cache.push(img);
        return img;
    }
    GMICMapType.prototype.realeaseTile = function (tile) {
        var idx = this.Cache.indexOf(tile);
        if (idx != -1) this.Cache.splice(idx, 1);
        tile = null;
    }
    GMICMapType.prototype.name = "Lok Darpan";
    GMICMapType.prototype.alt = "Lok Darpan News";
    GMICMapType.prototype.setOpacity = function (newOpacity) {
        this.opacity = newOpacity;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Cache.length; i++) {
            this.Cache[i].style.opacity = newOpacity; //mozilla
            this.Cache[i].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + newOpacity * 100 + ")"; //ie
        }
    }

    function getWindowHeight() {
        if (window.self && self.innerHeight) {
            return self.innerHeight;
        }
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function resizeMapDiv() {
        //Resize the height of the div containing the map.
        //Do not call any map methods here as the resize is called before the map is created.
        var d = document.getElementById("map");
        var offsetTop = 0;
        for (var elem = d; elem != null; elem = elem.offsetParent) {
            offsetTop += elem.offsetTop;
        }
        var height = getWindowHeight() - offsetTop - 16;
        if (height >= 0) {
            d.style.height = height + "px";
        }
    }

    function load() {
        resizeMapDiv();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centreLat, centreLon);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: initialZoom,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 4,
            center: latlng,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["ImageCutter"]
            },
            mapTypeId: "ImageCutter"
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        gmicMapType = new GMICMapType();
        map.mapTypes.set("ImageCutter", gmicMapType);

    }

    //]]>
</script>
```

Here is html to call api and to load Map

```
<body onresize="resizeMapDiv()" onload="load()">
    <div class="body">
        <div role="main" class="main">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have used GMAP ImageCutter tool to make custom tiles.
You can duplicate the problem here http://www.lokdarpandainik.com/

Answer (score 0):

It was because of other bootstarp CSS overriding the feature of google map.
To get rid of this I have overridden the bootstarp by declaring

```
#map img{
            max-width: none !important;
        }
```

targeting the div in which I manipulated custom map (i.e. div id="map" in this given code).